# Is it bad idea to make domain User implementing UserDetails interface?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I dont want to implement code that copies necessary User fields to UserDeails in case having special implementation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I don't think it as a bad idea. In [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon), we have our `User` implement `UserDetails`. In another project, we had a `UserDetailsImpl` which held a `User` object, and could be constructed like this: `new UserDetailsImpl(user)` - so no copying was needed.

Both did well.